# MySQL check if date interval is taken

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with a lot of rows containing start_date and end_date in the format 'YYYY-mm-dd'

And dont want a taken period to be overlapped, or wrapped around a taken period

```
Row 1: start_date 2020-07-01 , end date 2020-15-07

Row 2: start_date 2020-06-14 , end date 2020-06-29
```

and if i test with new start_date 2020-06-13 , end_date 2020-06-30 , row 2 should be returned

and if i test with new start_date 2020-06-16 , end_date 2020-06-30 , row 2 shoudl be returned.

and if i test with 2020-06-27 and end_date 2020-07-02 row 1 and 2 should be returned

How is that made, cannot get my head around it.

Comment: Check your data again. What is 2020-15-07?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a variant of the overlapping range problem.  You may consider:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE end_date >= new_start AND start_date <= new_end;
```

For example, to use sample data your provided, you might try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE end_date >= '2020-06-13' AND start_date <= '2020-06-30';
```

### Demo

Comment: Thats it, I have tried almost everything else,  Thank you so much.